# phantomjs-1.9.8 installation on 32bit windows operating system

Tags: phantomjs

I have downloaded the phantomjs -1.9.8 on windows operating system.and on double click  on the phantomjs.exe it is pointing to commandpromt,and i dont have any command to run over there. so any one provide me the detailed installation of phantomjs on windows operating system.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please tell us: 1) do you know what a command prompt is and how to invoke it on windows? 2a) if so - what exactly did you type? 2b) if not, what happened when you googled for "windows command prompt") ? :)

Comment: 1)yes 2)a phantomjs --version

Comment: Hi, can anyone provide me the detailed  installation procedure for phantomjs -1.9.8 version on windows 7

Comment: You are not yet providing us with enough information to help you... what installation information were you following that got you to where you are? Plus - we are going to help  you find your own solution... that's how it works. You can't just demand a full installation guide from people who are trying to help you in our own spare time... please be more considerate, and help us to help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: i want to use Phantomjs for exporting aspx page in an asp.net application.so for that purpose i have downloaded the phantomjs.exe along with supporting files.but when try to install by clicking on phantomjs.exe i will be prompted to command promt.and after that how to go ahead with installation.

Comment: people often don't read comment threads (and the formatting is awful)... can you please edit your original question and put all the information in there.